# How to exclude a list of strings from a autofilter in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to automate a process where I remove blanks and all names in a specific column apart from a list of specific names. Below is what I have for removing blanks from a specific column

```
'Remove Blank Users
Hold.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 22)).AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$I$" & last_row).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Field 20 includes a list of names and I only want to remove the one's that do not meet the criteria of the list of names I have I.e. User 1, User 2, User 3. But the list of names to remove will be ever-growing.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub removeFilteredNames()
  Dim Hold As Worksheet, last_row As Long, arrN
  
  'create the names to be removed array:
  arrN = Split("User1,User3,User6,User8,User10", ",")
  
  Set Hold = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
  last_row = Hold.Range("A" & Hold.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  'you must have the names in column T:T.
  'if they are in a different column, please, adapt the 'field' number:
  Hold.Range(cells(1, 1), cells(1, 22)).AutoFilter field:=20, _
                         Criteria1:=arrN, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  Hold.Range("$A$2:$I$" & last_row).SpecialCells _
                    (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select 'Delete
End Sub
```

The above code only selects the rows to be deleted. If it behaves as you need, you must only replace `Select` with `Delete`...

I think, it is obvious that you cannot have names containing spaces in their string name...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is I know who to keep as this will always be a constant. While the users that I need to remove is always changing

Comment: @bfreeman0: I am afraid I cannot get you... Did you test the above code? Does it work for a list made by you, to have a correspondence in the existing range, of course? If yes, did it work as you need? If not, what did not happen as you want? Then, The array can be built if you imagine an algorithm to be used for doing it. Otherwise, how do you imagine that a code can read your mind in terms of existing/non existing users...? What do you want, in fact?